# Laravel Execute sql queries from an sql file

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Because for testing there's no testing database I use a manually generated sql script to clean a database clone of my production database. Assuming that my the legacy database is the following:

```
ohimesama
id: PK
namae: Varchar (200)

oujisama:
id: pk
namae: Varchar(200)


ohimesamagasuki:
id: pk
ohimesama_id: fk ohimesama
oujisama_id: fk oujisama
```

And the test database cleanup sql (cleanup.sql) script is:

```
DELETE * from ohimesama where namae not in ['Gardinelia', 'Jasmine'];
DELETE * from oujisama where namae not in ['Gaouron', 'Sasuke','Aladin'];
DELETE * from ohimesamagasuki where ohimesama_id not in (SELECT id from ohimesama) and oujisma not in
(SELECT id from oujisama);
```

And because I want to be able to execute all theese commands with one transaction IU want to be able to read the `cleanup.sql` file and execute the sql commands using Laravel Database Layer without the need for writing it manually.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in this medium [article](https://medium.com/@suhkha/laravel-import-sql-file-with-a-custom-command-139fb8a84ad) you can use this one single liner:

```
    DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('cleanup.sql'));
```

The only issue is that sql commands are not chunked so in large sql files it may cause a slowdown. Also `file_get_contents` has a read limit as well.

In case of large sql files is reccomended to manually read and chunk it into selerate sql commands.

Also if a single command fails to get executed does not proceed to the next one as you would in via `mysql` or `psql` commands in a shell environment